# Customizing view to restrict only documents inside the document set?

Tags: sharepoint-online, features

I have created document sets in SharePoint and trying to create a view which can show only the items inside the document set. However when i am saving the view i am able to see all the items and also the document set folder. Can anyone help me in customising the view to restrict view only for items?

Answer (score 2):

### How to exclude Document Sets from List View using filters

Assume we have OOTB `Document Set` content type (`0x0120D520`) added in Documents Library, then  the following  filter could be specified:

```
Content Type is not equal to Document Set
```

[image]